# Converting json array to query string gives null

Tags: javascript, json, query-string

What I am trying to achieve is to send a json object as a querystring to an API.

The json object I have is:

```
{
  "Name":"Dlsajdsa",
  "ImageUrls":["/Images/Facility/8353/85e26a18-4366-4412-b37a-72d94f2ccda5.jpg"]
}
```

I would like to convert this to something like ?Name=&ImageUrls=

However, when using $.param(json) I get the following:

```
?Name=Dlsajdsa&ImageUrls%5B%5D=%2FImages%2FFacility%2F8353%2F85e26a18-4366-4412-b37a-72d94f2ccda5.jpg
```

This result, on the API point of view, that the ImageUrls array is null.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `$.param(json,true)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation of [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/), I'd say this is the piece of code you want to use:

```
var json = {
  "Name":"Dlsajdsa",
  "ImageUrls":["/Images/Facility/8353/85e26a18-4366-4412-b37a-72d94f2ccda5.jpg"]
};

var recursiveDecoded = decodeURIComponent($.param(json));

// "Name=Dlsajdsa&ImageUrls[]=/Images/Facility/8353/85e26a18-4366-4412-b37a-72d94f2ccda5.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

The query parameter is called `ImageUrls%5B%5D`, that means `ImageUrls[]`, not ImageUrls as you expect.